Software Updater UI is missing the "Upgrage" button
I am trying to migrate my "Linux Mint 20.3 Una" desktop to the latest ang gratest available version, following instructions in https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#2-launch-the-software-updater which are similar to many other sources.
The thing is that the "software updater" tool window does not show the "Upgrade" button (see attached snapshot: SW Updater window)
Any idea as of what could be wrong?

Mint is not Ubuntu. It has a different set of tools. That version of Mint is quite old, and may be unsupported, and upgrade path may be closed. If you want to use latest version of Mint, please download the ISO and fresh install. If you want to use Ubuntu, please do the same

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
